# DRF .as_viewset on {'post': 'list'} return attribute error?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to send some text: example: "Hello World" to DRF end-point.

This endpoint on receiving this text is to send me a e-mail with the text.

When I hit the end-point with Postman, I get the error:

> Internal Server Error: /api/errors
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/sid/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
> File "/Users/sid/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> File "/Users/sid/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
> File "/Users/sid/eb-virt/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 117, in view
> handler = getattr(self, action)
> AttributeError: 'ErrorMsgViewSet' object has no attribute 'list'

To test this out:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .api import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/errors', ErrorMsgViewSet.as_view({'post': 'list'}), name='errors'),
]

# I tried .as_view(), which gave me an error to change to the above format
# i tried using router.register() and got errors on using generic.GenericAPIview
```

api.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from email_alerts.serializers import ErrorsSerializer


class ErrorMsgViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ErrorsSerializer
    permission_classes = [
        
    ]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


# Create your models here.
class ErrorsModel(models.Model):
    error_msg = models.CharField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from email_alerts.models import ErrorsModel


class ErrorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    error_msg = serializers.CharField(
        required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ErrorsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mapping such that a POST request is mapped to the `list` view, which is *strange*, so you need to implement a `list` method:

```
class ErrorMsgViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = ErrorsSerializer
    permission_classes = []

    def list(
        self, request, *args, **kwargs
    ):  # 🖘 will be triggered with a POST request
        print(request.data)
        # …
```

You probably however do *not* want this mapping, so you register it with:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #                 map a POST request to post 🖟
    path('api/errors', ErrorMsgViewSet.as_view({'post': 'post'}), name='errors'),
]
```

and then thus implement a `post` method.

Comment: It is a strange mapping. I tried the `as_viewset()` instead of `.as_viewset({'post': 'list'})`. It gives me errors: >TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`. I am not sure why this would happen and how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sid: why not just `.as_view()` *without* the dictionary?

Comment: I tried it without the dictionary: .as_view(). The server starts showing this error: TypeError: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`. I am reading about the issue here: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3742

Comment: @Sid: what about `.as_view({'post': 'post'})`?